# get all database names from oracle 11g Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I can able to connect the Oracle Database.

I have a Task to List out all the Databases Names in the ComboBox or List, array.

I need query to get the result

While searching, i found the list all the tables query.

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM user_tables
```

I don't have any idea about the Oracle DB.

I'm using the Windows 8 OS for development purpose.

Comment: This sounds unclear to me. Please have a look at [mcve] to improve your question and make it clearer. As a starting point, consider posting your table structure, some sample data and the data you need to get from your tables

Comment: "List out all the Databases Names "..Are you referring to objects of the database

Comment: Yes, i need query to list all the database names.

Comment: Do you really want a comboBox with all the names of all the tables, constraints, sequences, indexes... ?

Comment: Some terminology explained 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37012/difference-between-database-vs-user-vs-schema

Comment: I need TWO Queries, 
1) I need a query to list all the database names in LIST object
2) I need a query to list all the table names to given DB Name.

Comment: "database names" does not make much sense. Names of what? A DB has tables, indexes, constraints, schemas ... what names do you need?

Comment: Yes. I need only DB Names to display it UI (i.e) ComboBox or List Box.

Comment: I believe you should better have a look at what DB, instance, schema, user, ... mean in Oracle, then rephrase your question in a clearer way.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one database on 11g XE (unlike SQL Server and MySQL).  You can have multiple schemas which your application might use.

You can list all the schemas with

```
SELECT username FROM all_users;
```

Although this will include many built in schemas which you would most likely want to exclude by adding something like

```
WHERE username NOT IN ('ANONYMOUS', 'APEX_030200', 'APEX_040200', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER', 'APPQOSSYS', 'AUDSYS', 'CLOUD_ENGINE_USER', 'CLOUD_SWLIB_USER', 'CTXSYS',
        'DBSNMP', 'DIP', 'DMSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'DVF', 'DVSYS', 'FLOWS_030000', 'FLOWS_FILES', 'GSMADMIN_INTERNAL', 'GSMCATUSER', 'GSMUSER',
        'LBACSYS', 'MDDATA', 'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW', 'OJVMSYS', 'OLAPSYS', 'ORDDATA', 'ORDPLUGINS', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'ORDSYS', 'OUTLN', 'OWBSYS',
        'SCOTT', 'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'SYS', 'SYSBACKUP', 'SYSDG', 'SYSKM', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSMAN_APM',
        'SYSMAN_MDS', 'SYSMAN_OPSS', 'SYSMAN_RO', 'SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS', 'OWBSYS_AUDIT', 'WKPROXY', 'WKSYS', 'WK_TEST', 'WMSYS', 'XDB', 'XS$NULL');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER FROM ALL_OBJECTS;
```

to get distinct values from the database

Comment: "
'MDSYS',
'PUBLIC',
'CTXSYS',
'SYSTEM',
'APEX_040000',
'SA',
'XDB',
'SYS'
"

i got it while execute the above query. Here which one is Database Name

Comment: @venkat - Each of those is the name of a schema.  There will only ever be one database in XE and that database name will always be XE.  If you really want the list of databases `select 'XE' from dual`.  Otherwise, as the answers point out, you probably really want to list schemas.  Whether you want to list only the schemas that have objects the current user can access (this answer) or all schemas in the database (@Lunc's  answer) is a question you'd need to answer.